# Implementing ng-repeat for 2 parameters

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to print a list which has 2 elements (binded dynamically)taken from 2 different arrays.

Following is my code:
**scopehie.html**

```
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scopehie.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        Hello {{name}} !! </br></br>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
        <ol>
            <li ng-repeat-start="name in names", ng-repeat-end="dept in department">{{name}} from {{dept}}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**scopehie.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp' , []);

app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $rootScope.department = 'Angular' ;
}) ;

app.controller('childCtrl' , function($scope){
    $scope.names = ['A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D'];
    $scope.department = ['M' , 'N' , 'O'];

});
```

The problem is that my first parameter i.e "name in names" is looping but the second parameter i.e "dept in department" is not looping , infact it is not showing at all.

Output shown :

Hello World !!

1.A from
2.B from
3.C from
4.D from

Output required :

Hello World !!

1.A from M
2.B from N
3.C from O
4.D from P

Kindly suggest something.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, as in what is the resulting HTML you'd want to see in your example case?

Comment: ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end can be used for same data either names or department.

Comment: So is there no way to iterate both of them i.e. names and department ?

Answer (score 1):

try this simple `$index` way

```
<li ng-repeat="dept in department">{{names[$index]}} from {{dept}}</li>
```

You can do it by using `ng-repeat` only. not needed start and end .

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this :

```
<ol>
   <li ng-repeat="name in names">  
   {{name}} from {{department[$index]}}</li>
</ol>
```

The thing is you can use ng-repeat on just one veriable. While ng-repeat-start and -end is for repeating a block of html tags instead of just one tag. So...

Comment: Sorry bro. I was busy writing the answer. I am gonna upvote yours one only... :)

Comment: Thanks...I have the desired output now

Answer (score 0):

If there is one to one mapping between **names** and **department** then you can do in this way.

`<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}} from {{department[$index]}}</li>`

Answer (score 0):

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PVI4m8z1nZFbRov8mDlY?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    Hello {{name}}
    <br>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="childCtrl">
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="name in names">
        {{name}} from {{department[$index]}}
        <br>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>
```